# Strategy for handling case sensitivity of javascript properties

Tags: javascript, properties, intellisense

I'm sure someone is going to shout at me for asking this question, but here goes: in Javascript, what is the best strategy for coping with the fact that the properties of objects are case-sensitive?  If I create an object with a property called FavouriteDrink, but then I later start referring to it as favouriteDrink then I could end up in a mess.

I don't want a big library here, but is there any way to define the object so that FavouriteDrink is defined somewhere, and where in Visual Studio 2012 some intellisense will help me choose the correct property name if I can somehow contextualise the object I'm dealing with?  It is only properties I'm pondering here.

Thanks.

Comment: Just make a rule. Tattoo it on your arm. Always use it. The properties will always be camel-case start with a lower case. Or maybe the properties will be all lower case with underscore between words. Or always start with upper case. (I like the first one.) Use whatever rules suits you but always use the same rule.

Comment: There are established coding conventions for javascript. But you're only asking for configuring intellisense?

Comment: @Bergi - well, things like firstname can be a bit vague - is it firstname or firstName.  With a team of people coding against the same  codebase I just wondered if there was a way of making this a bit more concrete - intellisense seems a helpful thing in this circumstance if it can be made to 'know' about existing properties

Comment: @VAGABOND - I'm not looking to change the conventions, just to introduce clarity to coders when there is scope for interpretation within the convention.

Comment: @whatdoesitallmean that's just it though, the convention is pretty comprehensive and leaves little room for interpretation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work this way

if i look at your your code and see :

```
FavouriteDrink() {}
```

the first thing will popup in my mind is this is a constructor function not just a normal function

and by looking at this following one

```
favouriteDrink() {}
```

i would tell that this is a normal function and i can't use it as a constructor - can't be called with `new`

Here is some other examples

```
 first_name // variable 
 FIRST_NAME // uppercase variables shouldn't change 
 _first_name // local variable not intended to be used out of its scope 

 var FIRSTNAME = {}  // name space
```

**it’s a good idea to follow a convention as to how the words will be separated**

see this [Code Conventions for the JavaScript Programming Language](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html)

For the other part of your question i'm using VS 2012 and i installed `JSEnhancements`

and i can see all my object element

[image]

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript shares the following conventions with Java and ActionScript 3.

### ALL_UPPERCASE

Use this as the variable name when you define a constant, or a value that should never change.

For example, `myObject.NUM_TIMES_CLICKED = 2` would be a poor candidate for a constant because it is likely to change. However, `myObject.APPLE_FRENCH_SPELLING = 'pomme'` would be appropriate here.

### firstWordLowercaseAndTheRestAllUppercase

Use this when you are defining **anything** that is not a `constant` or a `class`. You would use this for most things, for example, `myObject.numTimesClicked`, `myObject.myFunction()`, `myObject.returnString`.

### AllWordsCapitalized

Use this when you are defining a function that defines a "class," generally any function you would call with the syntax `myObject.myClassInstance = new MyClass()`. Notice how `myClassInstance` is in camel-case because it is an instance of the class. However, `MyClass` is all caps because it is meant to be invoked with `new.`

You would define the class initially like this: `myObject.MyClass = function(){};`

Comment: OP is aware about the conventions,he is asking for alternatives!!!and some intellisense..

Comment: Reading the OP's comments, this has nothing to do with coding conventions. It has to do with IntelliSense providing existing properties

Comment: Maybe OP should consider using conventions since they are conventions.

Comment: @itcouldevenbeaboat Then you should say that (would be duplicated because others have already suggested that) in the comments, but it's unrelated.

Comment: @Ian - thank you, you are spot on.  On the rare occasions where the conventions could be inadvertently incorrectly applied by someone is there any way to guide the coder...

Answer (score -1):

[WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) and [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) are great tools that offer the code intelligence you're looking for.

WebStorm does this out of the box, but my personal preference is Sublime Text with the [SublimeCodeIntel](https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel) plugin.

That being said, it's probably best for you to be using naming conventions:

- UpperCamelCase is for classes
- ALL_CAPS_SNAKE_CASE is for constants
- lowerCamelCase is used for everything else

Comment: Thanks very much.  What do you tend to do with things like firstname or lastname?

Comment: I would do firstName, and lastName. For me I find it helps to have super consistent, hard rules, so = each word gets camel-cased. I also like to write expressive variable and function names, like function findUserByFirstName (firstName) {...}. Hope that helps!